# Как переносить текст в TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-textview

У меня есть, например, такой текст: "Вот какой-то \n рандомный текст"

Как сделать так, чтобы в TextView на первой строке было "Вот какой-то ", а на второй " рандомный текст"? Просто использование \n не помогает

Comment: Помогает. Проверьте

Comment: Покажите XML-разметку `TextView`.

Comment: Я создаю программно

Comment: ![Вот скриншот](https://pp.userapi.com/c836231/v836231473/2eab4/otG2gvp9JQA.jpg).

Comment: Значит покажите как создаете и как добавляете текст.

Comment: `TextView textView = new TextView(rootView.getContext());



        textView.setText(text);

        textView.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

        textView.setTextColor(GRAY);

        if(isBold && isItalic){
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf"));

textView.setTextSize(textHeight);

        linearLayout.addView(textView, lParams);
`

Comment: Текст, например, подается такой: _так выглядят картинки \n \n сверху была одна пустая строка_

Comment: Интересно, что если я использую `textView.setText("рандомный \n текст");` , то текст переносится..

Comment: Ещё я заметил, что метод replaceAll вообще не находит символ "\n", хотя по логам видно- в тексте он есть. Такое не работает `text = text.replaceAll("\n", "\n");`

Comment: Проблема решилась следующим образом:вместо `\n` я начал вставлять в текст `/n` , и потом использовать метод `text = text.replaceAll(" /n", "\n");`